# convertir un recurso en byte array sin escribir en disco

Tags: c#

Mi pregunta es:

Hay alguna manera de convertir  un recurso directamente a byte array sin necesidad de escribir en disco?

El código es:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace VCSKicks
{
    public static class ResourceHelper
    {
        public static string GetEmbeddedResource(string resourceName)
        {
            return GetEmbeddedResource(resourceName, Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
        }

        public static byte[] GetEmbeddedResourceAsBytes(string resourceName)
        {
            return GetEmbeddedResourceAsBytes(resourceName, Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
        }

        public static string GetEmbeddedResource(string resourceName, Assembly assembly)
        {
            resourceName = FormatResourceName(assembly, resourceName);
            using (Stream resourceStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            {
                if (resourceStream == null)
                    return null;

                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resourceStream))
                {
                    return reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }

        public static byte[] GetEmbeddedResourceAsBytes(string resourceName, Assembly assembly)
        {
            using (Stream resourceStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            {
                byte[] content = new byte[resourceStream.Length];
                resourceStream.Read(content, 0, content.Length);

                return content;
            }
        }

        private static string FormatResourceName(Assembly assembly, string resourceName)
        {
            return assembly.GetName().Name + "." + resourceName.Replace(" ", "_").Replace("\\", ".").Replace("/", ".");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: y el código que utilizas actualmente, ¿Cuál es?

Comment: La respuesta a ambas preguntas es si.

Comment: tal vez usando la clase resourcehelper ? http://www.vcskicks.com/embedded-resource.php

Comment: el código es sobre un articulo que lei en el cual lo lee directamente pero no llego a entender bien como leer el recurso , puse la clase por si alguien sabe mas del tema.

Comment: El código que tienes parece correcto y no utiliza archivos intermedios. Cual es el problema que tienes?

Comment: una vez que añadi el recurso que debo hacer? con esto seria suficiente? VCSKicks.ResourceHelper.GetEmbeddedResourceAsBytes("nombre de mi recurso")

Comment: Pues si, con eso debería bastar al ser un método estático. De todas maneras, lo mas sencillo sería probarlo y si tienes algún problema comentarlo :)

Comment: Es solamente el nombre del recurso como string lo que debes pasarle. Si te fijas en el código, este se encarga de generar el nombre del recurso obteniendo el assemby y uniendolo al nombre que tu le pasas.

Comment: esque cuando lo leo como recurso me coge el 50% cpu y nunca lo lee puse lo siguiente: VCSKicks.ResourceHelper.GetEmbeddedResourceAsBytes("nombre de mi recurso")  y se queda el programa pausado consumiendo el 50% del cpu